# How to replace a disk mounted to a specific folder without losing the stored data

Tags: raid, storage

Disk 1 is mounted to /storage, it is 99% full and I am out of spare connectors. What I want to do is replace Disk 1 with a bigger drive (Disk 2) in a way that the new larger disk will contain the same data from the old disk and points to the same folder without having the data hidden. I will be temporally disconnecting another disk to do whatever process I have to do. However, no disk other than 1 and 2 can hold the data, so I can't use an intermediary storage location.

Disk 1 is under a normal ext4 partition.

My idea is to create a RAID1 between the two disks, give it enough time for the data to be mirrored, then simply disconnect DISK1. My questions are: Will the act of creating the RAID1 remove the data on DISK1? Will removing DISK1 give me back the full size of DISK2? Is this is a safe way to do it? Is there an easier way?

Comment: "without having the data hidden" -- you mean, like, no downtime for the copy, the filesystem's still mounted and writable the whole time, or what?

Comment: @jthill I am of the understanding that if I just connect disk2 and copy the data from disk1, then point disk2 to /storage, the data won't show up and will not be (simply) reachable. Which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If you have LVM on your old disk, in theory you should be able to extend it onto the new one, then shrink it again to only live on the new one. But I never tried that, so don't hold me to it.

Comment: hmm, it's tagged RAID but this is just a bunch of disks. and JBOD tag is not available,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect both disks up and copy the data,

Seeing as the disk is mostly full an image copy (eg using dd) will probably be the fastest means, but care must be taken that the copy is in the correct direction.

after copying adjust the partition size and grow the filesystem out to match the new size.

finally connect the nw disk where the old one used to connect and update /etc/fstab as apropriate.

Comment: There was no need to update fstab as when I used the new disk with the old's disk connectors it had the same name. The only hiccup along the way was changing the disk to gpt, as the size was over 2TB. Anyway, everything is working well, thank you!